# value of λ so that the improper integral exists

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

For which value of  $\lambda \in\Re $ the improper integral I exists
$$I=\int_0^\infty (\frac{x+1}{3x^2+λ}-\frac{λ}{2x+1})dx. $$

I tried to calculate the integrals separately but no effect. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly if $\lambda=0$, $I$ diverges. Now suppose $\lambda\neq0$.
Note
$$I=\int_0^\infty (\frac{x+1}{3x^2+λ}-\frac{λ}{2x+1})dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{(2-3\lambda)x^2+2x^2+3x+(1-a^2)}{(3x^2+λ)(2x+1)}dx. $$
If $\lambda\neq\frac23$, then
$$ \frac{(2-3\lambda)x^2+2x^2+3x+(1-a^2)}{(3x^2+λ)(2x+1)}\approx\frac{2-3\lambda}{6x}$$
when $x$ is large. Since $\int_1^\infty\frac1xdx$ diverges, hence $I$ diverges.

If $\lambda=\frac23$, then
$$ \frac{(2-3\lambda)x^2+2x^2+3x+(1-a^2)}{(3x^2+λ)(2x+1)}\approx\frac{1}{3x^2} $$
when $x$ is large. Since  $\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^2}dx$ converges, hence $I$ converges.

Answer (score 3):

If $\lambda = 0$, then the integrand behaves like $\frac{1}{3x}$ as $x \to 0$, whose integral around zero diverges. So we must have $\lambda \ne 0$.

If $\lambda \ne 0$, then the integrand behaves like $\frac{1}{\lambda} - \lambda$ as $x \to 0$ which is fine. It remains to check the convergence of the upper tail.

---

As $x \to \infty$ the integrand behaves like $(\frac{1}{3} - \frac{\lambda}{2}) \frac{1}{x}$, so if $\frac{1}{3} \ne \frac{\lambda}{2}$, there exists a constant $c > 0$ such that for all large $x$ one of the following happens.
$$\frac{x+1}{3x^2 + \lambda} - \frac{\lambda}{2x+1} \ge \frac{c}{x}
\qquad \text{or} \qquad
\frac{x+1}{3x^2 + \lambda} - \frac{\lambda}{2x+1} \le -\frac{c}{x}.$$
In either case, the integral diverges as $x \to \infty$. So we need $\lambda = 2/3$.

Comment: thanks for the answer :) is there any other approach?

Comment: for λ=2/3 the right integral is still infinity :(

Comment: It would be nice if you accepted the answer.

Comment: @KostasGiatzo I think you can show that if $\lambda = 2/3$ the integrand decays like $c/x^2$, so the integral converges.